# Status Report - Reporting Expired Duration

Tags: progress-report

I'm creating a status report for my project and I want to report that we have used 44 out of our scheduled 144 days. The 44th days is simply the current Thursday when I submit my status report. I want to compare this number with two other key indicators, amount of the budget that has been spent and amount of work that has been completed. Is there a standard way of wording that?

Currently I have the comments below but it feels misworded

...

**Budget:**

Overall 50%

Contract Labor 25%

**Time:**

Phase 1 Deliverable - Sept 27th

44 / 144 working day used (30%)

**Deliverables:**

2 / 10 Major Tasks Complete

3 / 10 In Progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of any metric depends on the message you are trying to convey.  What is it about duration exhausted that is meaningful to the health of your project?  If you can answer that question, then the language for displaying the metric should be self evident.

The issue you have is, days exhausted does not mean anything.  The 30% does not necessarily mean, or even likely means, some level of completion.  It is merely a passage of time.  Days remaining is a bit more meaningful ONLY if it is accompanied by the PM's latest revised estimate of days remaining, e.g., 100 budget days remaining, PM LRE = 110 days remaining.

What is more important is physical percent complete, i.e., what should have been accomplished by this arbitrary day 44 and what, then, are your variances.

Comment: I updated the question to give better context. I wanted to compare the number of days expired to amount of budget used and tasks completed. Days exhausted sounds better than working days used.

Answer (score 3):

Explore [Earned Value Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earned_value_management).  EVM is a way to compare the number of days expired to the budgeted cost and time.  Although people make EVM sound very complicated, it isn't; it is a good way to tell if you are ahead of, behind, or right on track for what you predicted.